# When using on_member_join, how do I get the message from the bot to be sent to a specific channel that I want?

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I'm trying to create a bot that sends a welcome message when a member joins the guild, however I can't figure out how to get the message to be sent to the specific channel that I want.

My code so far:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', case_insensitive=True)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game(': The Moon Song'))
    print("bot is read to use")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member: discord.Member = None):
    name = member.display_name
    embed = discord.Embed(title=(f'{member} has joined the guild! \nWelcome!'), description = 'please nativate to #rules and read all relavent information\nWe hope you enjoy your stay here <3', colour= 0xFFF0A1,)  
    embed.set_image(url='https://media.giphy.com/media/26xBz5092fHa8usx2/giphy.gif')
    await member.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `disocrd.utils.get`to get the #welcome channel by its id. Also, no need to use `(member: discord.Member = None):`, here is how to use `disocrd.utils.get` -

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', case_insensitive=True)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game(': The Moon Song'))
    print("bot is read to use")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    name = member.display_name
    embed = discord.Embed(title=(f'{name} has joined the guild!\nWelcome!'), description = 'please nativate to #rules and read all relavent information\nWe hope you enjoy your stay here <3', colour= 0xFFF0A1,)
    embed.set_image(url='https://media.giphy.com/media/26xBz5092fHa8usx2/giphy.gif')
    await member.send(embed=embed)
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.text_channels, id="<your #welcome channel's ID>")
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

---

**References-**

[discord.on_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_join)

[discord.utils.get](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get)

Comment: wait, I'm having issues with entering the ID ;-;, how do you do it? the error comes out as an indentation error...

channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.text_channels, id=[numbers])

Answer (score 0):

This is how i would do it

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', case_insensitive=True)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game(': The Moon Song'))
    print("bot is read to use")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member: discord.Member = None):
    channel = client.get_channel(ID) # Where ID is your welcome channel's ID.
    name = member.display_name
    embed = discord.Embed(title=(f'{member} has joined the guild! \nWelcome!'), description = 'please nativate to #rules and read all relavent information\nWe hope you enjoy your stay here <3', colour= 0xFFF0A1,)  
    embed.set_image(url='https://media.giphy.com/media/26xBz5092fHa8usx2/giphy.gif')
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: How do I enter the channel id? 
 await member.send(embed=embed)
 channel = client.get_channel(id=[numbers])
 await channel.send(embed=embed)

but it says unindent does not match any indentation level

Comment: Here is an example: channel = client.get_channel(706723568628662303) <--- You would replace those numbers with your channel id. By the way that error indicates that you have an indentation issue.

Comment: no need to use `id=` you can just simply put the id of the channel inside the `()`, example - `(1234)`

Comment: yes, i tried doing that my line of code is:
```channel = Client.get_channel(4897xyz) ```
it still comes up with an indentation error even though i'm pretty sure it's ok? all the lines of code are in line with each other

Comment: You might be mixing tabs and spaces.You can check using python -m tabnanny -v yourfile.py